# Is it possible to bound $C_1x^{-2\alpha}+C_2x^{2\beta+1}\le C_3$ from below?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

Consider the inequality

$$\underbrace{C_1x^{-2\alpha}+C_2x^{2\beta+1}}_{(\ast)}\le C_3$$

where $C_1,C_2,C_3>0$ are positive constants which all depend on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and $\alpha,\beta>0$ are positive exponents and $x\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$

Is it possible to bound $(\ast)$ from below? I was also wondering if one could estimate $x$, but I suppose that this is out of the question

Comment: where is $x$ defined?

Comment: @don-joe My apologies; I edited the post now

Comment: I guess $C_3$ depends on $C_1, C_2, \alpha, \beta$ is that right? If so, can you be specific? Maybe the estimation for $C_3$ helps understand how one could arrive for an inequality from below. Also obviously $0$ comes to mind as bound from below.

Comment: @don-joe $C_3$ depends on $\alpha,\beta$...and actually, the LHS and RHS of the inequalities are the upper and lower bounds respectively of a function and were very complicated to derive. I was actually hoping to bound from below by a nonzero constant.

I am not sure, but I think the negative exponent may be of assistance

Comment: "algebra-precalculus" So, we cannot use calculus?

Comment: @mathlove I used the tag "algebra-precalculus" because I thought the problem was quite elementary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

$y=C_1x^{-2\alpha}$ is decreasing, and $y=C_2x^{2\beta+1}$ is increasing.

So, there is only one real solution for $C_1x^{-2\alpha}=C_2x^{2\beta+1}$. Let it be $x=\gamma$.

For $0\lt x\le\gamma$,
$$C_1x^{-2\alpha}+C_2x^{2\beta+1}\ge C_1\gamma^{-2\alpha}+0=C_1\gamma^{-2\alpha}$$

For $\gamma\lt x$,
$$C_1x^{-2\alpha}+C_2x^{2\beta+1}\gt 0+C_2\gamma^{2\beta+1}=C_1\gamma^{-2\alpha}$$

It follows from these that, for $x\gt 0$,
$$C_1\gamma^{-2\alpha}\le C_1x^{-2\alpha}+C_2x^{2\beta+1},$$
i.e.
$$C_1\left(\frac{C_1}{C_2}\right)^{\frac{-2\alpha}{2\alpha+2\beta+1}}\le C_1x^{-2\alpha}+C_2x^{2\beta+1}$$